# Why isn't this algorithm for the Josephus problem working in c, when it works in python?

Tags: python, c, josephus

So I needed to solve a version of the Josephus problem, in which we assume we have n robots standing in a circle, all of which are on in the beginning. We start to turn the robots off in rounds.
Robot number 1 is turned off in the first round, then we count the robots that are on until we reach number k, and we turn that robot off.
The process goes on until exactly one robot remains on.

So the problem is that we should write an algorithm that takes n and k as input and prints an array of the robots turned off each round in order.
For example if n = 13 and k = 2, the answer would be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 4, 8, 12, 6, 2

I wrote a python code for the problem, with the intention to convert it to C afterwards
Here's the python code, to show the general idea of the algorithm:

```
n = int(input())
first = list(range(1 , n + 1)) 

k = int(input())

result = [] # with n - 1 segments

def removal(i):
    while i < len(first) - 1:
        first[i] = first[i + 1]
        i += 1
    first.pop() # n -= 1

i = 0
while len(first) > 1: # n > 1
    result.append(first[i])
    removal(i)
    i += k-1
    i %= len(first)

print(result)
```

And here's the C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n , k;
    scanf("%d" , &n);
    scanf("%d" , &k);
    int len = n;
    int first[n + 1];
    
    int j = 0; //Taking array first as input
    while (j < n)
    {
        first[j] = j + 1;
        j++;
    }

    int result[n - 1];
    int i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (n > 1)
    {
        result[j] = first[i]; 
        j++;

        while (i < n-1) //Removing the i th item of array first
        {
            first[i] = first[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
        n--;
        i += (k-1);
        i %= n;

    }
    
    j = 0;
    while (j < len-1)
    {
        printf("%d " , result[j]);
        j++;
    } 

    return 0;

}
```

For example, in the case I mentioned above, for n = 13 and k = 2, the C code prints:
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

As I said, the python code works, but the C version of it doesn't and I can't figure out why.
Can anyone explain what I should do to fix the code in c?

Comment: This is the ideal code to [learn to use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/21105992) on. Give it a try.

Comment: In the Python program, you have two variables named `i`. In the C program, you have but one you use for both purposes, and thus contains garbage.

Comment: The Python code has a function `removal(i)`, the C code has nothing like that. Maybe start with bringing C code to be closer to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that python uses pass by value (see [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)) and your C program does not copy the value of `i` while removing the `i`'th element, it rather modifies it. If you change part of your removal loop to:

```
int m = i;
while (m < n-1) //Removing the i th item of array first
{
    first[m] = first[m + 1];
    m++;
}
```

It should work like you expect. This is rather not a question for stackoverflow as you might have guessed from the comments you got.

Comment: I'm not seeing your point about parameter passing convention.  Python and C both pass parameters only by value.  In Python, the values are all references, because that's the only kind of values it has, but that ends up not differentiating it from C with respect to numeric types or lists / arrays.

Comment: Now that I look carefully at the OP's C program, I suspect I know what you mean. Nevertheless, bringing pass-by-value into it is just confusing.

Comment: I see your point, but for me, it was vital to understand the difference of both programs, maybe I should have phrased it differently. Nevertheless, I think the comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m-could-be-an-ai, would be sufficient here.